# Number of positive divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given the following number "$11..11$" -$1992$ ones repeated-, prove that the number of positive divisor is even.

I came up with the following idea: pick the number and rewrite the number this way:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{1992}{10^i}=\sum_{i=0}^{1992}{2^i5^i}=2^05^0+2^15^1+\cdots+2^{1992}5^{1992}$$

And, the only common divisor to all those number is $1$ and the big number itself, only two divisors. So the amount of positive divisors of the whole number must be even.

Does this make any sense?

Thanks you

Comment: Your approach is interesting but doesn't work. Breaking a number into a sum doesn't tell you much about its divisors; for example, $121 = 1 + 20 + 100$, and the only common divisor of $1, 20$, and $100$ is $1$, yet $121$ has an odd number of divisors. To put it another way, if your logic worked, you could apply it to any given number, which would then imply that no number has an odd number of divisors; this is clearly false.

Comment: No progress, unfortunately. Our number $N$ is $\frac{1}{9}(10^{1992}-1)$. It has two obvious divisors, $1$ and $N$, but quite a few more, since $10^{1992}-1$ can be factored in various ways. Finding all the divisors by hand sounds quite unpleasant, and is a challenge for a computer. However, the question can be answered without knowing the divisors.

Comment: From how you've rewritten the number: Divide by $4$ and find the remainder. Note that your first two terms are not divisible by $4$, but the rest are (i.e., from $2^2 5^2$ on). So all of those later terms disappear, and the first two terms sum to $11 = 2(4) + 3$, which means, after dividing by $4$, the remainder is $3$. **Meaning:** Dividing your number by $4$ leaves a remainder of $3$, but any square number divided by $4$ has a remainder of $0$ or $1$; so yours cannot be square. [See my answer for more.]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Hint** For any integer $n$ if $d$ is a divisor of $n$ then so is $\frac{n}{d}$. As long as $\frac{n}{d}\neq d$ they are a pair, and you can pair the divisors.

Use this idea to show that any number which is NOT a perfect square has an even number of divisors.

**Hint 2**
$$111...1=\frac{1}{9} 999..999=\frac{1}{9}(10^{1992}-1)$$

Use the fact that $10^{1992}$ is a perfect square to show that your number cannot be a perfect square.

Comment: This seems to me a bit more involved than noting the number is $3 \text{ mod } 4$ hence not a square!

Comment: @BenjaminDickman It is a mater of taste, but to me showing that two (non-trivial) consecutive integers cannot both be perfect squares is simpler than using modular arithmetic; as it only requires knowledge gained in secondary school.

Answer (score 10):

The number $11..11$ is divisible by $3$ since the sum of its digits is $1+1+...=1992$=multiple of $3$ but not by $9$ since the sum of its digits is not divisible by $9$.
So, the number you investigate is not a perfect square  and therefore it has an even number of divisors.

Comment: I think there's a step in the middle that I don't understand....how does the number being a multiple of $3$ but not $9$ mean the number is not a perfect square?

Comment: @BrianJ, think about the prime factorization of a perfect square. Each prime factor must appear an even number of times so it can be in both "sides" of the squaring. But if there were an even number of $3$ s in the prime factorization of $11..11$, then we could group them together and divide $11..11$ by 9. Since we can't, we know that $11..11$ isn't a perfect square.

Comment: @Kevin makes sense now. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: +1, nice observation. But even if there were, say, 1998 concatenated 1s, it could not be a square... (despite 1998 being divisible by 9). [See my response.]

Comment: @BenjaminDickman of course there are many ways to see that it is not a square.

Comment: True, I just thought that your approach -- which is totally valid, and for which I voted you up! -- risks being taken to indicate implicitly that $1992$ has a special property insofar as it's div. by $3$ and not $9$, which is the key to seeing it's a non-square... when, as I've noted, any string of $\geq 2$ ones concatenated is not a square!

Answer (score 6):

**Fact 1:** Every integer squared is congruent to either $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$.

**Fact 2:** $1\ldots1 \equiv 3 \text{ mod } 4$.

Therefore, $1 \ldots 1$ is not a square. **QED**

---

In case the two facts here are unclear or unknown, let us establish each:

**Fact 1:** Any number is $0, 1, 2,$ or $3$ modulo $4$; squaring and reducing modulo $4$ again, the results are $0, 1, 0, 1$, respectively. Thus, the first fact is established.

**Fact 2:** Observe $11 = 8 + 3$, and $111 = 108 + 3$, and $1111 = 1108 + 3$, etc. Looking at the right hand side in each case, the former addend is divisible by $4$, and the $3$ stands alone. Thus, reducing modulo $4$ establishes the second fact.